# varios usuarios un login

Tags: sql

buenas tengo una duda estoy trabajando en sql server y quisiera saber si en un mismo login puede haber varios usuarios? ya que cuando lo intento me sale:' El inicio de sesión ya tiene una cuenta con otro nombre de usuario.'

Comment: Aumm puedes explicar un poco más el problema no entiendo bien cuando indicas en un mismo login.

Comment: creo un login(servidor) a una base de datos a ese quiero añadirle varios usuarios de base de datos()

Comment: Deberías crear un usuario que pueda arrancar la base de datos y tenga los derechos que sean necesarios para realizar los procesos que necesites en la base de datos.  Posteriormente utilizas una conexión que utilizará ese usuario, y tus programas usarán esa conexión para acceder a SQL Server, aunque tengas cientos de usuarios usando la misma conexión.  Si accedes desde una aplicación web, por ejemplo, la web utiliza una sola conexión (o varias) y en ella hay multitud de usuarios simultáneos.

Comment: Otra opción:   El problema es que pusiste como propietario al mismo LOGIN. Se soluciona dejando al propietario como <predeterminado> y luego agregando el login como usuario a la bd.